What is the cycle index polynomial of the action of the general linear group $GL(5,2)$ on $5$-dimensional affine space over ${\mathbb{F}_2}$?
Work over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_2 = \{0, 1\}$ with $2$ elements. What is the cycle index polynomial of the natural action of the general linear group $GL(5,2) = GL_5(\mathbb{F}_2)$ on $5$-dimensional vector space $ {\mathbb{F}_2}^5$? This group has order $|GL(5,2)| = (2^5 - 1)(2^5 - 2)(2^5 - 2^2)(2^5 - 2^3)(2^5 - 2^4) = 9999360$ and the space it is acting on has $|{\mathbb{F}_2}^5| =  2^5 = 32$ points.
By definition, the cycle index polynomial of this action is
$$Z(GL(5,2) \curvearrowright {\mathbb{F}_2}^5) = \frac{1}{|GL(5,2)|} \sum_{A \in GL(5,2)} {X_1}^{e_1(A)} \cdots X_{32}^{e_{32}(A)},$$
where $e_i(A)$ is the number of cycles of length $i$ in the disjoint cycle decomposition of the permutation $x \mapsto Ax \in Sym({\mathbb{F}_2}^5)$, where $x \in {\mathbb{F}_2}^5$ is a column vector with 5 entries and $A \in GL(5,2)$ is an invertible $5 \times 5$ matrix.
I do the case of $2 \times 2$ matrices over ${\mathbb{F}_2}$ here. The general linear group has order $GL(2, 2) = (2^2 - 1)(2^2 - 2) = 6$. There are 3 conjugacy classes, namely $[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}]$, $[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}] \sim [\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}] \sim [\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1\end{smallmatrix}]$, and $[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0\end{smallmatrix}]\sim [\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1\end{smallmatrix}]$. The cycle decomposition of the identity matrix $[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}]$ is $(\binom{0}{0}) (\binom{1}{0}) (\binom{0}{1}) (\binom{1}{1})$, so its cycle index monomial is $X_1^4$. The action of $[\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0\end{smallmatrix}]$ sends $\binom{0}{0} \mapsto \binom{0}{0}, \binom{1}{0} \mapsto \binom{0}{1}, \binom{0}{1} \mapsto \binom{1}{0}, \binom{1}{1} \mapsto \binom{1}{1}$, so its cycle decomposition is $(\binom{0}{0}) (\binom{1}{1})(\binom{0}{1} \,\, \binom{1}{0})$ and its cycle index monomial is ${X_1}^2 {X_2}$. The action of $[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0\end{smallmatrix}]$ sends $\binom{0}{0} \mapsto \binom{0}{0}, \binom{1}{0} \mapsto \binom{1}{1}, \binom{0}{1} \mapsto \binom{1}{0}, \binom{1}{1} \mapsto \binom{0}{1}$, so its cycle decomposition is $(\binom{0}{0}) (\binom{1}{0} \,\, \binom{1}{1} \,\, \binom{0}{1})$ and its cycle index monomial is ${X_1} {X_3}$. Therefore, taking the weighted average,
$$Z(GL(2,2) \curvearrowright {\mathbb{F}_2}^2) = \frac{1}{6}({X_1}^4 + 3 {X_1}^2 X_2 + 2 X_1X_3).$$
There is actually a formula by Fripertinger (see Theorem 1 in the reference):
$$Z(GL(n,q) \curvearrowright {\mathbb{F}_q}^n) = \frac{1}{[q]_n} \sum_\gamma \sum_\lambda \frac{[q]_n}{\prod_{i = 1}^{A_n} b(d_i, \lambda^{(i)})} \times_{i = 1}^{t_n} \times_{j = 1}^{\gamma_i} (x_1 \prod_{k = 1}^j x_{e_{ij}}^{a_{ik}})^{\times \lambda_j^{(i)}}.$$

Surely $e_{32}(A)=0$ for all $A$. And perhaps relevant: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Aspects-of-the-linear-group-GL5-2_tbl1_262858724, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2389922_The_Classes_of_GLn2_n6

Sledgehammer approach: Use the computer (i.e. GAP):
gap> g:=GL(5,2);;
gap> v:=GF(2)^5;;
gap> perm:=Action(g,v);
Group([ (17,25)(18,26)(19,27)(20,28)(21,29)(22,30)(23,31)(24,32), (2,3,5,9,17)
  (4,7,13,25,18)(6,11,21,10,19)(8,15,29,26,20)(12,23,14,27,22)
  (16,31,30,28,24) ])
gap> CycleIndex(perm,[1..32]);
1/9999360*x_1^32+1/21504*x_1^16*x_2^8+1/1536*x_1^8*x_2^12+1/384*x_1^8*x_2^4*x_\
4^4+1/504*x_1^8*x_3^8+1/128*x_1^4*x_2^6*x_4^4+1/24*x_1^4*x_2^2*x_3^4*x_6^2+1/3\
2*x_1^4*x_2^2*x_4^6+1/180*x_1^2*x_3^10+1/21*x_1^4*x_7^4+1/12*x_1^2*x_2*x_3^2*x\
_4*x_6*x_12+1/16*x_1^2*x_2*x_4^3*x_8^2+1/12*x_1^2*x_3^2*x_6^4+1/15*x_1^2*x_5^6\
+1/7*x_1^2*x_2*x_7^2*x_14+2/15*x_1^2*x_15^2+2/21*x_1*x_3*x_7*x_21+6/31*x_1*x_3\
1

The cycle index thus is
$$
\frac{1}{9999360}x_1^{32}+\frac{1}{21504}x_1^{16}x_2^8+\frac{1}{1536}x_1^8x_2^{12}
+\frac{1}{384}x_1^8x_2^4x_4^4+\frac{1}{504}x_1^8x_3^8+\frac{1}{128}x_1^4x_2^6x_4^4\\
+\frac{1}{24}x_1^4x_2^2x_3^4x_6^2+\frac{1}{32}x_1^4x_2^2x_4^6+\frac{1}{180}x_1^2x_3^{10}
+\frac{1}{21}x_1^4x_7^4+\frac{1}{12}x_1^2x_2x_3^2x_4x_6x_{12}\\
+\frac{1}{16}x_1^2x_2x_4^3x_8^2+\frac{1}{12}x_1^2x_3^2x_6^4+\frac{1}{15}x_1^2x_5^6
+\frac{1}{7}x_1^2x_2x_7^2x_{14}+\frac{2}{15}x_1^2x_{15}^2\\
+\frac{2}{21}x_1x_3x_7x_{21}+\frac{6}{31}x_1x_{31}
$$

thanks ahulpke. Is it true for quantities like the cycle index, it's more common to use a computer than the work it out by hand, once the dimension (here 5) gets significantly large?

@ColinTan It depends on what you want to achieve. If you just want one particular cycle index concretely, with terms collected together,  the computer will likely be quicker and avoid arithmetic errors (that I would do by hand).

thanks for sharing your reason to use the computer.
